Solving $x^a\equiv b \pmod {p^m}$
I am studying number theory by my own (I'm not a math major but I'm very interested in this, so I'm sorry I don't know much) and I was wondering if there is a result that says if this next equation has a solution: $$x^a\equiv b \pmod {p^m},$$  with $m, a$ and $b$ given integers, $p$ prime.
I have the feeling this has a solution module $p^m$ if $(a,\phi(p^m))=1$ but I don't know if there is a result for this. Or maybe I'm totally off. If someone has any help, I would appreciate it. The books I'm reading don't have this, or I haven't seen it.

To solve this would mean you would be able to extract $a$th roots mod $p^m$, which AFAIK is a hard problem.

Okay, thanks, I haven't gotten to that part of the text yet. However, is there for example a particular case for a=3 and p=2?

A solution always exists and is unique if $\gcd(a, \varphi(p^m)) = 1$ and $\gcd(b, p) = 1$, and is given by raising $b$ to the power of $a^{-1} \bmod \varphi(p^m)$. Otherwise solutions may not exist and when they do they may not be unique, but we can say some things about when that happens.

The easy case (cf. prior comment) is described in many answers, e.g. here. $\ \ $

@QiaochuYuan Thank you very much. Is there a textbook where I can find this?

@BillDubuque I apologize for not searching more throughly. Thank you for replying, I appreciate it.
